Added logic to jetton contract FunC but lost the contract_type = jetton master attribute
I have cloned jetton contract and added some logic inside, but when I deployed, the contract lost contract_type=jetton_master, does this have any effect, and is there any way to fix it, thank you very much[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/vRacD0o7.png)
I deleted the new variables and tried again and the contract works fine, so how can I add logic to Ton Func's jetton standard?

The contract type is based on its code, so you can't just change it and expect that the contract is recognized as jetton_master. Unless you provide the code that you've used, it's not possible to answer more specifically than "check if your code follows the Jetton standard".
Please also note that the algorithm used by tonviewer (which you are asking about, as far as I can see from the image) is probably not open source, so it can be stricter or more loose than the standard, hence following the standard doesn't guarantee that tonviewer will recognize your contract as jetton_master (in the most strict case, I will only do so if your code is exactly the same as the standard implementation).
